# Suggest a good Android development workflow

Tags: java, android

I'm interested in developing android applications. I've a background of Java/Swing/C++/ajax developer so I think I may find myself at home. As I installed the SDK I noticed that I can't follow my usual java development scheme: building base libraries, then the final app. In fact I'd like to develop libs and test them in a more convenient environment like, Swing. There is no way I can use android libs in pure swing apps...
Do you have any suggestion about these topics and what's your development process?

Answer (score 1):

If you have written a lib that does call functions from the android jar, you can write JUnit 4 tests in a separate Project and execute them to test your lib functions. This forces you to keep some of your functionality separated from the android specific things and you can then be sure that all the errors you tested for are gone before you introduce the problems that can arise if you are running on the device. You can do JUnit Tests on the emulator too but that is a little bit more complex.